# How to use ng-required with input type as file?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form in angularjs where an image(logo) needs to be compulsory to upload only when a particular check box is checked,and even if the checkbox is not selected the user may upload the image but in that case it's not compulsory. I tried using ng-required for conditional required functionality but it's not working with the file input.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isTrue" ng-change="isChecked()"/>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.check = false;
$scope.isChecked = function() {
   $scope.check = true;
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choose File" ng-model="uploadFile" ng-required="check" />
```

May I get help from anyone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

I wanted a file upload functionality and I did it as follows.

Hope this helps.

```
    <form id="uploader" ng-submit="uploadImage()" role="form">
        <input id="image" type="file"  required />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="button btn-success form-control" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="button btn-danger form-control" />
    </form>
```

This ensured me on selecting a file(image) in order for the user to submit.

Comment: this doesn't address the functionality provided by ng-required, where you can conditionally set required based on an expression that angular evaluates.